# referring taglib from localhost

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, taglib

I understand that to use jstl on JSP, one need to include this taglib in the jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to refer this item via localhost.

====

For example, I can use this jquery which I downloaded and placed in my resource folder

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead of referring jquery from http://ajax.googleapis.com

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

====

Question: is there a way to refer jstl from local folder, instead of look up at http://java.sun.com?

Asking this question is because my client wanted a web app hosted on local network and have no internet access. so, no external referencing.

p/s: please no chit-chat, just written solution.

p/s/s: please don't advise me to change my programming language, framework or upgrade my java version. It is a restriction for my work.

Answer (score 1):

The URI is a Universal Resource Identifier, it is NOT a locator (URL) or src of file.

This means that the URI is used to uniquely identify each taglib in an internal registry of taglibs.

This URI is specified in ***.tld** files in jstl jar. You can check it extracting jar and goto **jstl-1.2\META-INF**

So you cannot change this URI. It is accessible even without internet.